# What does "bracketing" a UK political party mean?

Tags: united-kingdom, election

In the article *[PM strikes secret deal with DUP as he draws up 'final Brexit offer'](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/oct/01/johnsons-final-warning-to-the-eu-accept-my-brexit-deal-or-its-no-deal)* by
Lisa O'Carroll , Heather Stewart, Daniel Boffey and Rowena Mason it says:

> "Johnson will draw up battle lines for the general election –
>   including seeking to **bracket** Labour with the Scottish National party,
>   a move the Tories used successfully against Ed Miliband’s Labour party
>   in 2015."

What does "bracketing" mean? How would this affect the election and why presumably would it be in the interest of the Conservative Party to do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this context Bracketing means grouping them together. Suggesting that neither party has enough support to win an election on their own and that instead a vote for either means a vote for both. Johnson wishes to suggest that the election is between the Conservatives and a Labour-SNP coalition, allowing him to paint each opposition party with the unpopular policies of the other.

[David Cameron](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2015/apr/17/david-cameron-labour-snp-coalition-of-chaos) did the same in 2015.

> claiming the Labour leader would be in hock to Scottish nationalists if he was allowed to form a minority government.

Comment: So you mean it is just a statement by the PM, and has no actual practical effect?

Comment: Yes. There's so much more I want to put in this answer, like the strong and stable tweet, or the current Conservative DUP arrangements, but I think that's probably straying beyond the question.

Comment: Similar the term "ConDems" is used to group the Conservatives and Liberal Democrats together, and is particularly used by Labour activists to associate Liberals with the austerity policitics of Cameron's coalition government.